Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 3.3.0
I've gone through all of the fixes for this. I do not/nor have I ever had ruby 2.6.10 installed on this machine. I'm not sure where this came from. I tried regressing to ruby 3.2.0 for something but reverted that I'm not able to run rails s or rails c without getting this error
Ignoring racc-1.8.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.8.0
Ignoring bigdecimal-3.1.8 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 3.1.8
Ignoring io-console-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine io-console --version 0.7.2
Ignoring psych-5.1.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine psych --version 5.1.2
Ignoring stringio-3.1.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine stringio --version 3.1.1
Ignoring bigdecimal-3.1.8 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 3.1.8
Ignoring io-console-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine io-console --version 0.7.2
Ignoring psych-5.1.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine psych --version 5.1.2
Ignoring stringio-3.1.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine stringio --version 3.1.1
fIgnoring bigdecimal-3.1.8 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 3.1.8
Ignoring bindex-0.8.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.8.1
Ignoring bootsnap-1.18.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.18.3
Ignoring bson-5.0.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bson --version 5.0.0
Ignoring byebug-11.1.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine byebug --version 11.1.3
Ignoring date-3.3.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine date --version 3.3.4
Ignoring debug-1.9.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug --version 1.9.2
Ignoring ffi-1.16.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.16.3
Ignoring io-console-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine io-console --version 0.7.2
Ignoring jaro_winkler-1.5.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine jaro_winkler --version 1.5.6
Ignoring json-2.7.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.7.2
Ignoring msgpack-1.7.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine msgpack --version 1.7.2
Ignoring nio4r-2.7.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.7.3
Ignoring pg-1.5.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine pg --version 1.5.6
Ignoring prism-0.30.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine prism --version 0.30.0
Ignoring psych-5.1.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine psych --version 5.1.2
Ignoring puma-6.4.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine puma --version 6.4.2
Ignoring racc-1.8.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.8.0
Ignoring rbs-3.5.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine rbs --version 3.5.1
Ignoring rbs-2.8.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine rbs --version 2.8.4
Ignoring sassc-2.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sassc --version 2.4.0
Ignoring stringio-3.1.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine stringio --version 3.1.1
Ignoring strscan-3.1.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine strscan --version 3.1.0
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.6
Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 3.3.0

Anyone know what this could be?
My Gemfile, .ruby-version all use 3.3.0
I use asdf to manage versions, I've uninstalled and reinstalled ruby 3.3.0 so many times. I've reshimed. I've tried updating bundler and rubygems. I'm just at a loss as to how it can be trying to reference a version that I've never installed.
I've also tried
asdf uninstall ruby 3.3.0
rm -rf ~/.gem/gems
rm -rf ~/.gem/specs
gem cleanup
asdf install ruby 3.3.0
gem install bundler

But anytime I try to do something rails related it gives the above error :(
EDIT I'm able to use bundle exec rails s|c but I didn't need that prerequisite before :(

Is this on a Mac? When did the problem start?

Yes, macbook M2. Just started today. Not sure if it's something to do with downgrading the ruby version for a minute or not :(

it could be picking up the ruby that was installed with the OS. Find it and delete it. You might be able to find it running "which ruby" from the rails root.

it's a good idea to use a ruby version manager such as rvm or rbenv. It will help "tame" your ruby versions.

which ruby == /Users/usrname/.asdf/shims/ruby. I've been using asdf for years and never ran into this before

What does ruby -v output? What does asdf list ruby output? Since bundle exec works it appears this is an issue with the current ruby and not the existence of a specific ruby install.

➜  ~ ruby -v
ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [arm64-darwin23], ➜  ~ asdf list ruby
*3.3.0

I found whereis ruby and got ➜  ~ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1 not sure if that is significant
